# How Mundy's arm knew the gyroscope was inside Volkov?

Tags: analysis, the-cloverfield-paradox

In the movie [The Cloverfield Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cloverfield_Paradox), Mundy's arm gets pulled into a solid wall, and is severed clean off; and after sometime they found the hand moving its on.

When they recognize that it is trying to write something, they give a pen and it writes to cut Volkov open. And when they do they found the gyroscope inside Volkov.

How did the hand knew it was inside him?

Comment: Honestly I don't think that whole angle made any sense. It felt kind of forced in and it was never really explained.

Comment: @Phlegon_of_Tralles, the whole movie felt forced and never really explained....

Comment: Right, but there was the veneer of science in their attempt to explain what happened (the alternate reality). So, from a certain perspective some of what they suggest *made sense according to the movie's internal logic*. This part was never explained and just didn't make any sense.